# Can't directly access array inside of StdClass object?

Tags: php, arrays, stdclass

I'm having trouble accessing an array inside of an StdObject. The object looks like this in my debugger:

```
$obj = {stClass}[9]
  1234 = {array} [28]
    0 = "some text"
    1 = false
    2 = true
    3 = ""
  ...
```

It seems like I should be able to access elements in the array like this:

```
$tmp = 1234;
echo $Obj->$tmp[0]
```

But I get `Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$5`

However, when I do this:

```
print_r($Obj->$tmp);
```

It prints out the array just fine.

Why am I unable to access an element in the array, even though I can print out the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What PHP version are you one, something like this would work for me:

```
echo $Obj->{$tmp}[0]
```

On PHP >= 5.1

Reasoning behind this I think is because `$tmp[0]` is translated before accessing the object as oppose to translating `$tmp`, then access the object via `$tmp`

Comment: That worked for me. I've never encountered this behavior before and it seems really strange. Is this a bug with PHP?

Comment: @Nate I wouldn't say it is a bug with PHP, just the way the syntax works.